# Which OAuth2 grant type should I use?

Tags: perl, oauth-2.0, mojolicious

I'm maintaining SReview, a mojolicious-based webapp which needs to run a lot of background tasks that will need to change database state. These jobs require a large amount of CPU time and there are many of them, so depending on the size of the installation it may be prudent to have multiple machines run these background jobs. Even so, the number of machines that have access to the database is rather limited, so currently I'm having them access the database directly, using a direct PostgreSQL connection.

This works, but sometimes the background jobs may need to run somewhere on the other side of a hostile network, and therefore it may be less desirable to require an extra open network port just for database access. As such, I was thinking of implementing some sort of web based RPC protocol (probably something with JSON), and to protect the access with OAuth2. However, I've never worked with that protocol in detail before, and could use some guidance as to which grant flow to use.

There are two ways in which the required credentials can be provided to the machine that runs these background jobs:

1. The job dispatcher has the ability to specify environment variables or command line options to the background jobs. These will then be passed on to the machines that actually run the jobs in a way that can be assumed to be secure. However, that would mean that in some cases the job dispatcher itself would need to be authenticated with OAuth2, too, preferably in a way that it can be restarted at will without having to authenticate again and again.
2. As the number of machines running jobs is likely to be fairly limited, it should be possible to create machine credentials for each machine. In that case, it would be important to be able to run multiple sessions in parallel on the sale machine, however.

Which grant flow would support either of those models best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From overview of your scenario it is clear that interactions occur among system to system. There is no end user (a human) user interaction.

First, given that your applications are executed in a secure environment (closed) they can be considered as confidential clients. [OAuth 2.0 client types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) explain more on this. With this background, you can issue each distributed application component a client id and a client secret.

Regarding the grant type, first I welcome you to get familiarize with all available options. This can be done by going through [Obtaining Authorization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4) section. In simple words it explain different ways an application can obtain tokens (specially access token) that can be used to invoke OAuth 2.0 protected endpoint (in your case RPC endpoint).

For you, the best grant type will be [client credential grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4). It is designed for clients which has a pre-established trust with OAuth 2.0 protected endpoint. Also it does not require a browser (user agent) or an end user compared to other grant types.

Finally, you will require to use a OAuth 2.0 authorization server. This will registered different distributed clients and issue client id, secrets to them. And when a client require to obtain tokens, they will consume token endpoint. And each client invocation of your RPC endpoint will contain a valid access token which you can validate using token introspection (or any specific desired method).